# Sparx Enterprise Architect - sysml - how to model a configuration on a block definition diagram using specialization

Tags: inheritance, enterprise-architect, specialization, sysml

Using EA 16.1 - sysml.  I would like to model a specific configuration of block by specializing that block and modifying things like multiplicity or other properties.

I would like to model this on a block definition diagram (BDD) as described in "A Practical Guide to SysML", section 7.7.6, and not as a specific instance as described in the book "SysML for Beginners Using Sparx EA", chapter 4, section "Modeling Similar Types of Things".

The problem I encounter is that modifications to the specialized block are automatically reflected in the parent block (see pictures below).

I am new to EA and would appreciate input whether this type of modeling is possible in EA, whether I'm using the tool or sysml modeling techniques incorrectly.  Thanks.

Here's a very simple example.  The model includes parent Block "Vehicle" having 0..4 wheels.  Block "Motorcycle" specializes Vehicle.  (I'm unable to get EA to show Motorcycle's inherited parts.  In the diagram and on the block, I have selected the boxes to show inherited items, but this has no effect.  EA's website shows this should be possible:  (https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.1/guide_books/other_block_relationships.html).

[image]
I attempted to display the Motorcycle's wheel part using the Features - Parts/Properties window.  The Browser shows the Vehicle and Motorcycle each having wheel parts with multiplicity of 0..4.

[image]
When I rename the Motorcycle's wheel part name or change the multiplicity - specifically making the change to the wheel part located under Motorcycle in the Browser, the change is replicated in the Vehicle block.
[image]
I additionally tried to see if the tool's redefinition and subsetting capabilities accomplished the task, but was unable to determine how those functions worked.

Essentially, I would like the Motorcycle block to have specific wheel multiplicity (within the range defined by Vehicle). Given that Motorcycle specializes Vehicle, I would not expect the changes to propagate up to the parent block.